# How to selected all unique row and column in 2 dimension of Matrix

Tags: java, matrix

I implemented a easy source code to find all possible paths in matrix. Then selected the unique row and column. But due to time complexity how can we can get directly unique path?
This is my source code:

```
    import java.util.*;
public class MyAllPath {
    public static ArrayList<String> allPaths;
    public static void printpaths(double[][] matrix) {  
        String[] path = new String[matrix.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++)
    {
        printpaths(matrix, path, 0, 0, i);
    }
}

private static void printpaths(double[][] matrix, String[] path, int index, int row, int column)
{
    path[index++] = Integer.toString(column)+"|"+Double.toString(matrix[row][column])+"\t";
    row++;
    if (row == matrix.length)
        {
            print(path);
        }
    else if (row < matrix.length) 
    {
        int boundary = matrix[0].length-1;
        for (int i = column - boundary; i <= column + boundary; i++)
        {
            if (i > -1 && i < matrix[0].length)
            {
                printpaths(matrix, path, index, row, i);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void print(String[] path) 
{
    String myPath="";
    for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++)
    {
        myPath+=path[i]+" ";
        System.out.print(path[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    allPaths.add(myPath);
}


public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    allPaths =new ArrayList<String>();
    double[][] matrix = {{1, 2, 3},
                        {4, 5, 6}, 
                        {7, 8, 9}};
    printpaths(matrix);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
    for(int i=0;i<allPaths.size();i++)
    {
        String[] path= allPaths.get(i).split(" ");
        TreeSet<Integer> duplicateColumn = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        for(int j= 0;j<path.length;j++)
        {
            String[] word=path[j].split("\\|");

            for(int k=0;k<word.length;k++)
            {
                duplicateColumn.add(Integer.parseInt(word[0]));
            }
        }
        if(duplicateColumn.size()==path.length)
            System.out.println(allPaths.get(i));

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You pasted too much code :) If you only need help with optimization for the extracting of duplicates, show us only that part + init and output. No need to show all the print functions.
Can you give example for "unique row & column" ? for the given init data, what should be counted and what not.

Comment: Thank for your reply,This are my output(anyway you can run my code to get this output) 
`0|1.0  1|5.0  2|9.0  
0|1.0  2|6.0  1|8.0  
1|2.0  0|4.0  2|9.0  
1|2.0  2|6.0  0|7.0  
2|3.0  0|4.0  1|8.0  
2|3.0  1|5.0  0|7.0 ` 
for instant in the first row mean path 0 =